# Android Tabhost changes tab on orientation chnage

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using a TabHost in my main layout, which only has 2 tabs right now. If I'm on the second tab and change orientation the app returns me to the first tab. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code into your manifest file where the tabHost activity is defined. Android automatically persists the state of selected tab.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

It works for me.. And Also read dis Android documentation, which defines other techniques to persists activity states. [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: As per the link, I also needed to include "screenSize" for it to work on newer OS versions, but it did work. Thanks!